# CompactMap and an array in an array

Tags: swift

I want to combine two arrays thanks to `compactMap`. There are two lists - Stations and Sensors. In the Sensor object there is a property named: `stationId`. It helps to combine Sensors with Stations, but there is a problem.

Some sensors are owned by the same `stationId`. So one Station can own several Sensors. Three, five, or even one and so on. But I can't do it by `compactMap`. I always have only one Sensor per Station. How to fix this? How to make more Sensors per Station in my case?

```
 func setAddItemList(stations: [Station], sensors: [Sensor]) {
    
    if stations.count > 0 && sensors.count > 0 {
        
        addItemList = stations.compactMap { station in
            guard let sensor = sensors.first(where: { $0.stationId == station.id}) else {
                return nil
            }
            return AddItem(id: station.id, stationId: sensor.stationId, cityName: station.city!.name, addressStreet: station.addressStreet!, sensor: ([SensorItem(id: sensor.id, stationId: sensor.stationId, param: (ParamItem(paramName: sensor.param!.paramName, paramFormula: sensor.param!.paramFormula, paramCode: sensor.param!.paramCode, idParam: sensor.param!.idParam)))]) )
        }
        if addItemList.count > 0 {
            addItem.onNext(addItemList)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! Could you please post code of your CoreData Fetching process from the beginning. I think that the problem is there.

Comment: Hi! Do you mean the contents of the lists? I am using Realm Database

Comment: @AisultanAskarov Why do you assume this is about Core Data?

Comment: @beginner992 Because at this point everything is fine. I think you are just not fetching it correctly, or problem may also be in your XCDataModel.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a `forEach` on the sensors array to match each sensor with a station

```
sensors.forEach { sensor in
    guard let index = stations.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == sensor.stationId }) else {
        print("Failed to find a station for sensor \(sensor.id)")
        return
    }
    stations[index].sensors.append(sensor)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

One of these lines is 375 lines long, with 2 sets of unnecessary braces. Before I even do anything, just tidying this up makes it *much* easier to read:

```
func setAddItemList(stations: [Station], sensors: [Sensor]) {
    if sensors.count > 0 {
        addItemList = stations.compactMap { station in
            guard let sensor = sensors.first(where: { $0.stationId == station.id}) else {
                return nil
            }
            return AddItem(
                id: station.id,
                stationId: sensor.stationId,
                cityName: station.city!.name,
                addressStreet: station.addressStreet!,
                sensor: [
                    SensorItem(
                        id: sensor.id,
                        stationId: sensor.stationId,
                        param: ParamItem(
                            paramName: sensor.param!.paramName,
                            paramFormula: sensor.param!.paramFormula,
                            paramCode: sensor.param!.paramCode,
                            idParam: sensor.param!.idParam
                        )
                    ),
                ]
            )
        }
        if addItemList.count > 0 {
            addItem.onNext(addItemList)
        }
    }
}
```

The check for `stations.count > 0` does nothing, so I removed it.

I would replace this entire approach. `compactMap` is for mapping and filtering out `nil`s. In each invvocation of its closure, you're doing a linear scan through the sensors to find the first one that belongs to the station. That's slow, but as you found, it's also incorrect, because it'll always land on the same item.

Instead, I would use a dictionary to key sensors by their ID. Something like this:

```
func setAddItemList(stations: [Station], sensors: [Sensor]) {
    let sensorsByStationID = Dictionary(grouping: sensors, by: \.stationId)
    let sensorItemsByStationID = sensorsByStationID.mapValues { sensor in 
        return SensorItem(
            id: sensor.id,
            stationId: sensor.stationId,
            param: ParamItem( // FIXME: ParamItem is a terrible name
                paramName: sensor.param!.paramName,
                paramFormula: sensor.param!.paramFormula,
                paramCode: sensor.param!.paramCode,
                idParam: sensor.param!.idParam
            )
        )
    }

    let addItems = stations.map { station in 
        AddItem( // TODO: AddItem? What does that have to do with a "Station" or a "Sensor"?
            id: station.id,
            stationId: sensor.stationId,
            cityName: station.city!.name,
            addressStreet: station.addressStreet!,
            sensor: sensorItemsByStationID[station.id] ?? [] // FIXME: This keyword label should be `sensorItems`, not singular.
        )
    }

    if !addItems.isEmpty {
        addItem.onNext(addItems) // FIXME: this might be a misplaced responsibility in this function.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the very interesting answer!