# Combine two arrays by id

Tags: arrays, swift

I have two arrays and I need to combine them by an id. This is how it looks like:
Every single Station has its own sensors. One, two, three or even none. We can find them thanks to ids. Station has an id property, and Sensors are owners of stationId properties. Unfortunately I can't to download them together in one array, so I have to use two arrays. I want to display them in the list view, so I have to create array of objects where the data of both lists form one list. I have created combined array, but there every Stations has only one Sensor and this my problem.
I can't make array where Stations are owners more than one Sensor. In the code below you can see, that there is a problem with accessing elements. It always takes the first index, but I don't know how to get another ones with same id. I'm stuck

Station:

```
[{
"id": 14,
"stationName": "Działoszyn",
"gegrLat": "50.972167",
"gegrLon": "14.941319",
"city": {
    "id": 192,
    "name": "Działoszyn",
    "commune": {
        "communeName": "Bogatynia",
        "districtName": "zgorzelecki",
        "provinceName": "DOLNOŚLĄSKIE"
    }
},
"addressStreet": null
}]
```

Sensors:

```
[{
"id": 92,
"stationId": 14,
"param": {
    "paramName": "pył zawieszony PM10",
    "paramFormula": "PM10",
    "paramCode": "PM10",
    "idParam": 3
}
},
{
"id": 88,
"stationId": 14,
"param": {
    "paramName": "dwutlenek azotu",
    "paramFormula": "NO2",
    "paramCode": "NO2",
    "idParam": 6
}
}]
```

Edited code:

```
 func setAddItemList(stations: [Station], sensors: [Sensor]) {
        
        var stationItems = [StationItem]()
        var sensorItems = [SensorItem]()
        sensors.forEach { sensor in
            guard let index = stations.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == sensor.stationId}) else {
                print("Failed to find a station for sensor \(sensor.id)")
                return
            }
            let sensorItem = SensorItem(
                id: sensor.id,
                stationId: sensor.stationId,
                param: ParamItem(
                    paramName: sensor.param?.paramName ?? "",
                    paramFormula: sensor.param?.paramFormula ?? "",
                    paramCode: sensor.param?.paramCode ?? "",
                    idParam: sensor.param?.idParam ?? 0))

            sensorItems.append(sensorItem)

            if sensorItems.count == sensors.count {
                let stationItem = stations.map { station in
                    StationItem(
                        id: station.id,
                        stationId: sensor.stationId,
                        cityName: station.city?.name ?? "",
                        addressStreet: station.addressStreet!,
                        sensor: stationItems[index].sensors?.append(sensorItem) ?? []

                    )
                }
                stationItems.append(contentsOf: stationItems)                   
            }
            }
```

I also tested Dictionaries, but I had the same problem.

Comment: I believe this was answered in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65168570/compactmap-and-an-array-in-an-array)

Comment: Unfortunately not. Are incomplete Your idea was close, but didn't resolve the problem of combine arrays.

Comment: I tried, but your answer is too general. You wanted to assign sensors to stations, but it doesn't work in that way. Your idea was almost right, but first I need to make two lists: AddItem and SensorItem. Then I must assign SensorItems to AddItems. You wanted to just add one list to another. I need access to the properties.

Comment: And what's the desired output exactly?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson : Ok i edited code and trying to assign Sensors to Stations, but I have an error: Cannot convert value of type '()?' to expected argument type '[SensorItem]?'
I also changed name of AddItem to StationItem. Easier to read.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: I'll call you back later. Unfortunately I don't have time for quick answers, so I don't make sense. See you later and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First map Station to StationItem

```
var stationItems = stations.map { station in
    StationItem(
        id: station.id,
        stationId: sensor.stationId,
        cityName: station.city?.name ?? "",
        addressStreet: station.addressStreet!,
        sensor: [])
}
```

Then apply [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65168756/9223839) from your previous question but instead of appending a Sensor object you first map it to a SensorItem object as you are doing in your code above